# Anyone know when iOS 4.3 is due to come out?

Tags: iphone, ios

Anyone know when iOS 4.3 is due to come out?

I'm hoping to buy an iphone and use the wifi 'tethering' feature that apparently is part of ios 4.3 to replace our home internet connection, and am wondering when this is coming out?

Thanks all

Comment: More or less impossible to answer this question precisely. Of course, if you feel like jailbreaking you could always install MyWi, but not sure if that's an option for you or not.

Comment: I highly disagree with @Kyle closure of this question. Looking at [iOS version history](1), and knowing a bit about apple, we can predict some dates. Unfortunately I don't know all that much about apple as I've never witnessed any of their release.

Anyway, it will most likely come before June / July this year, when they must release iOS 5 or some other major release. There are rumors about February 28th and I believe it won't go beyond March.

Comment: @Cawas The only answers to this question will be pure speculation, the correctness of which can only be determined *after* iOS 4.3 comes out, at which time this question becomes no longer relevant.

Comment: @Kyle I agree. But he is asking for speculation. And even then there can be agreement over statistical expectations, which could be showed by answers being voted - just like any other question on these boards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be released when Apple feels like it's ready. It's anyones guess at this point. Apple almost never gives out release dates for it's products.

Like IntuitionGQ said, you can always Jailbreak it